# MySQL connection gone away when no op in a few minutes

Tags: mysql, connection

When using "mysql -h xxx -P xxx -u xxx -p xxx" to connect the mysql server with my terminal, I find the connection disconnected if no operations in a few minutes.
I have checked the interactive_timeout and wait_timeout option, and both them are 8 hours.
Can anyone explain the reason of the case and how to solve it ?[image]

Comment: If they where changed globally before the disconnection, they didn't apply to the current session. Global variable are copied to session variables when a new connection is made.

Answer (score 0):

I find that we use [dbproxy](https://github.com/Meituan-Dianping/DBProxy) as a forward proxy for mysql, and it has a restriction that when there's no operations in 2 minutes, the connection will be discard.
Because I was connecting to a db in testing environment, so I connect to mysql directly instead of using the dbproxy to solve the problem.